# Javascript syntax null : ?{}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

The example
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/PanResponderExample.js#L41

```
var PanResponderExample = React.createClass({
  ...
  circle: (null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void })
  ...
```

I don't know what does it mean `circle: (null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void })`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [flow](http://flowtype.org/)'s typecasts, you can see more details in this [post](http://flowtype.org/blog/2015/02/18/Typecasts.html)

> Typecasts are particularly useful to check assumptions and help Flow infer the types you intend. Here are some examples:
>
> ```
>   (x: number) // Make Flow check that x is a number
>   (0: ?number) // Tells Flow that this expression is actually nullable.
>   (null: ?number) // Tells Flow that this expression is a nullable number.
> ```

so `circle: (null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void })` is mean `circle` property is a nullable object which have a `setNativeProps` method and default value is `null`.

Comment: Might want to quote the most important part of the post.