# what does exports.displayName = (undefined: ?string); means in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

just started learning javascript this week. I have a very noob question. What does `exports.displayName = (undefined: ?string);` means in react native?

Is this trying to initialize undefined to exports.displayName as string

Thanks coders!

Comment: Can you please add some of your code that's giving this error ?

Comment: Have you googled the error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522233/javascript-undefined-empty-strings-and-if-statements

Comment: Are you using ternary operator?.If yes take a look at this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw(VS.94).aspx

Comment: ?: its conditional operator it will work as if else condition.

Comment: Is this supposed to be code? Or some output? It's definitely not standard JavaScript. Please provide more context.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear enough. I saw this in react native and i not quite sure what is it trying to do? is it trying to initialize undefined to exports.displayName as string?

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript syntax null : ?{}](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32721630/218196)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a (Flow? TypeScript?) **type annotation** for an optional string. It is not Javascript syntax. Yes, it does initialise `exports.displayName` with the value `undefined`.